# how to preserve data in form after a unsuccessful submit or after page reload after the error?

Tags: python, django, django-views, preserve

I have a Crud Project in which when i add any new member in the list the data i entered is vanished if i entered the same email which is already registered, i want that if i entered the mail id which is already registered so it will only give a message of that ID is already registered and data which i filled in the form it will not vanished , can we do this ?

```
type here
```

i want that if i entered the mail id which is already registered so it will only give a message of that ID is already registered and data which i filled in the form it will not vanished , can we do this ?

`Add_Member view.py`

```
    @login_required
    def user_data_create(request):    
            if request.method == 'POST':
                name = request.POST['name']
                email = request.POST['email']
                phone = request.POST['phone']
                gender = request.POST['gender']
                role = request.POST['role']
                if Members.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(request,"This Email Is already registred")
                else:    
                    user_data = Members.objects.create(user=request.user, name=name, email=email, 
                                                        phone=phone, gender=gender,role=role)
                    user_data.save()
                    messages.success(request,"New Member added Succesfully")
                    return redirect('dashboard_page')
            return render(request, 'add.html')
```

`Update View.py`

```
@login_required
def user_data_update(request, id):  
    
    
    try:
        user_data = Members.objects.get(id=id)
        if user_data.user == request.user:
            if request.method == 'POST':             
                user_data.name = request.POST['name']
                user_data.email = request.POST['email']
                user_data.phone = request.POST['phone']
                user_data.gender = request.POST['gender'] 
                user_data.role = request.POST['role']
                user_data.save()
                messages.info(request,"Member's Details Updated Succesfully")
                return redirect('dashboard_page')
            return render(request, 'update.html', {'user_data': user_data})
        else:
            raise Http404("You do not have permission to edit this data.")
    except Exception as e:
        messages.error(request,"This Email Is already registred ",e)
        return render(request,'update.html', {'user_data': user_data})
```

`Add.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Members</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</head>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

<body>
    <div>
        {%if messages%}
        {% for message in messages%}
        <div id="message_container" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
            **{{message}}**
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container1">
        <h1>Add Member</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'user_data_create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="">Name</label><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ user_data.name }}" pattern="^[^ ].+[^ ]$" title="Please Remove Extra Spaces" required><br><br>
            <label for="">Email</label><br><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ user_data.email }}" required><br><br>

            <label for="">Contact</label><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="{{ user_data.phone }}" title="Please enter exactly 10 digits" maxlength="10" minlength="10"
            pattern="\d{10}" required><br><br>

            <p>Please select Gender:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">
            <label for="male">Male</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
            <label for="female">Female</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">
            <label for="other">Other</label>

         


            <br><br>
            <label for="role">Select a Profile :- </label>
            <select name="role" id="role">
              <option value="None" selected>None</option>  
              <option value="FM">FM</option>
              <option value="TM">TM</option>
              <option value="TL">TL</option>
              <option value="Traniee" selected>Traniee</option>
            </select>   <br><br>
            
            
            
            <a class="button2" href="{% url 'dashboard_page' %}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="ID">Cancle</button>
                </a>
                <a class="button2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="ID">Submit<b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a form.. Maybe something like this:

user_form.py

```
from django import forms


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

and in your view pass it to template in the context.

Example for perserving data after submit:
In the view, you'll be doing something like this:

view.py

```
if not form.is_valid():
    return render(request, "your_template.html", {"form": form})
```

That will save the data after unsuccessful submit but not if you refreseh. To save the data when you refresh, I think you can use some storage like sessions.

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model form instead of plain html, and rendre the fields from the  form, the fields will be preserved after every request and you can always display them in the page, more details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) .